# loading more than one entry wtih search results from arrylist

Tags: java, android-studio, search, arraylist

I have these codes which work perfectly to search the data form my array list,but , its shows only one result of all the results that we got, I want the text view to view all the results that filtered to contain user input ( if there is a better widget to do this instead of text view it is fine for me).

//searchActivity.class //

```js
package com.example.boc.PhoneNumbers;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.boc.R;
import com.example.boc.main.phone_nombers_Activity;
import com.example.boc.models.Note;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class searchActivity extends phone_nombers_Activity {

    private DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
    public TextView resultsTxt , userinput ;

    public FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    public Note note ;
    public LinearLayout layout ;
    private ArrayList<Note> mNotes = new ArrayList<>();

    private DocumentReference noteRef = db.collection("notes").document();
    private CollectionReference notesCollectionRef = db.collection("notes");







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_search );

        final EditText userinput = findViewById( R.id.userInputtxt );
        final Button   findbutton = findViewById( R.id.findBtn );
        Button   openresultBtn = findViewById( R.id.openresult );
        final TextView previewResultTextview = findViewById( R.id.resultsTxt );




        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        CollectionReference notesCollectionRef = db
                .collection("notes");

        Query notesQuery = null;
        if(documentSnapshot != null){
            notesQuery = notesCollectionRef;

        }
        else{
            notesQuery = notesCollectionRef
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        }


        notesQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    String data = "";

                    for(final QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){
                        Note note = document.toObject(Note.class);

                        String title = note.getTitle();
                        String content = note.getContent();
                        data += "Title:" + title + "\nDescrition:" + content + "\n\n";
                        mNotes.add(note);
                        if( userinput !=null ) {
                            findbutton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    final String userinputString = userinput.getText().toString();

                                    Note match = null;
                                    String matcheddata ="";
                                    for (Note note : mNotes) {
                                        if (note.getTitle().contains(userinputString)) {
                                            match = note;
                                            String matchedtitle = match.getTitle();
                                            String matchedcontent = match.getContent();
                                            matcheddata += "Title:" + matchedtitle + "\nDescrition:" + matchedcontent + "\n\n";
                                            break;
                                        }

                                    }

                                    if (match != null) {
                                        // Found a match
                                        previewResultTextview.setText(matcheddata);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        previewResultTextview.setText( "no match found" );
                                    }




                                }

                            } );


                        }
                        else {
                            userinput.setError( "اسم الملف مطلوب" );

                        }





                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart () {
        final TextView previewResultTextview = findViewById( R.id.resultsTxt );

        super.onStart();
        notesCollectionRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    String data = "";

                    for(final QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){
                        Note note = document.toObject(Note.class);

                        String title = note.getTitle();
                        String content = note.getContent();
                        data += "Title:" + title + "\nDescrition:" + content + "\n\n";
                        mNotes.add(note);
                        previewResultTextview.setText( data );



                    }



                }}});
    }}
```

Comment: Use AutoCompleteTextView widget.

Comment: Remove the `break;`. That's what makes the loop... break as soon as you've found the first match.

Comment: @JB Nizet , now its load the same result twice after removing the break;